# Prevent sign-in box when opening MS-Word document, "Tell us the account you want to use...."

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, ms-word

We use MS Word automation to perform several actions to documents.  A few documents have started to get stuck when Word.Application.Documents.Open is called on them.

They are presenting a sign-in screen to what appears like a Sharepoint server.

I have tried to bypass this message using disabling the properties DisplayAlerts and AutomationSecurity, but the message still appears and freezes the automation program.

Is there a way I can prevent this prompt, or detect if the document is going to present it prior to trying to open the document?

```
Set obj_WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Const msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable = 3 
obj_WordApp.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable

Set obj_WordDoc = obj_WordApp.Documents.Open(Me.st_FileName, , False, False, "NO PASSWORD")
```

[image: Prompt]

Comment: could you download the document from SP separately...then open it in word separately?

Comment: We are processing the files on a server, and I do not have access to the Sharepoint.  It is a customer's sharepoint that the document is somehow referring to.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup single sign on then the popup shouldn't appear as the user is already authenticated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso

If that isn't an option you can try adding SharePoint/office 365 to the users trusted sites in the browser settings but I doubt it'll help much. Maybe configuring the users Credential Manager might help also but I doubt it also.